# C# - Blank screen when creating a new WPF Form..?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

So here is the problem: I have a basic application which uses a thread to call and update a new form containing a `textblock`. But the new form that is called is infinitely loading (blank screen) when it's called in my thread.

Here is my code that instantiates and calls the thread after clicking on a button:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread infoThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(update));
        infoThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        infoThread.Start();
    }
```

And here is the thread's function code:

```
private void update()
    {
        string response;

        InfoWindow infoWindow = new InfoWindow();
        infoWindow.Show();

        while(Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
        {
            response = sendRequest(1, 0, 3, 1, "test");
            infoWindow.tb_infoBlock.Text += response + "\n";
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

It basically creates a new `infoWindow` (The window that I actually want to update), and shows it. Then my thread calls a function that sends a request to a local server every X seconds and updates my `textBlock` with the response that is returned.

Note that I made my `sendRequest` function only return a 4 length string to try updating my block.

I really don't get the problem.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The thread that creates the window and loops never gets the time to update the window. It either reads, sets the text or sleeps.

Put the reading, setting and sleeping in an other thread and instead of setting the property directly use BeginInvoke of the form to have the form's thread update the UI of the form.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer, I understand what you are saying but wouldn't it be impossible to access the new form resources if I put those actions in an other thread?

Comment: @Chloecnoir - no. Threads can share resources. You can pass parameters/state to a thread. Just be very careful when reading and writing at the same time. That is why we have locks and dispatchers: they help prevent race conditions.